# Images not being found on DigitalOcean server

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, intervention

first things first!

I've created a route in my Laravel application to secure the images and then I used intervention/image to get them and show them to the users.

```
// Images Route
Route::get('/images/{folder}/{image?}/{size?}', ['as' => 'images', 'uses' => function($folder, $image, $size) {
    $path = storage_path() . '/app/' . $folder . '/' . $image;

    $img = Image::make($path)->resize(null, $size, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

        return $img->response();
}]);
```

Everything works perfectly on my local enviroment, by the way I'm using GD as image driver, but after a deployed my app to Digital Ocean I keep getting this 404 error.

I already double checked the storage folder and granted the right permissions but the error won't go away. **Someone knows what's going on?**

EDIT:
The server is running Nginx, but my computer is running Apache2. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Is that the only route you have?

Comment: Yeah, to load images it's the only one. The 404 I get specifically says this:

`The requested resource /images/users/admin.png/150 was not found on this server.`

Comment: That sounds like the route doesn't get hit, rather than that your code is wrong.

Comment: The route is getting hit! When a route doesn't exist the error is different. Still can't fix this... Already switch the routes name, url and place in routes file and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was duo the php built-in server that couldn't understand image intervention route.
Using the virtual host/server block it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I think Image::make expect path like:

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
```

Comment: I don't think so, because it accepts the path to a file... as long as it's a valid path I think it should work. **Anyway why would it work locally and not the server?**